# Merge sort not working in all cases

Tags: c, merge

I have written following code for merge sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergeSort(int array[],int left, int right);

void mergeArray(int array[],int left,int middle, int right);

void mergeArray(int array[],int left,int middle, int right)
{

    int n1 = middle - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - middle ;

    int temp_a[n1];
    int temp_b[n2];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for ( i = left ; i <= middle ; i++ )
    {
        temp_a[k++] = array[i];
    }

    for ( i = middle + 1 ; i < right + 1; i++ )
    {
        temp_b[j++] = array[i];
    }

    // now merge these two arrays


     i = 0;
     j = 0;
     k = 0;


    while ( i < n1 && j < n2 )
    {
        if ( temp_a[i] < temp_b[j])
        {
            array[k++] = temp_a[i++];

        }
        else
        {
            array[k++] = temp_b[j++];
        }
    }

    while ( i < n1 )
    {
        array[k++] = temp_a[i++];       
    }

    while ( j < n2 )
    {
        array[k++] = temp_b[j++];
    }



}


void mergeSort(int array[],int left, int right)
{
    // since there is only one element in the array.
    printf("I am in merge sort. left : %d, right : %d\n",left,right);
    if ( right - left < 1 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int middle = ( right - left ) / 2 ;
        mergeSort( array,left, middle );    
        mergeSort( array, middle +1 , right);

        mergeArray(array,left,middle,right);
    }


}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = 3;
    int i;

    int array[] = { 12,11,14,19};

    mergeSort(array,0,n);
    printf("\nArray is: \n");

    for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is working for `n = 1` and `n = 2` but not for other values.

Comment: Typo? `int temp_b[n1];` --> `int temp_b[n2];`

Comment: Try to debug your "mergeArray". The problem is likely there.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for pointing it out. But code is still not working.

Comment: @learner Are you using a debugger?

Comment: I am using linux + sublime text + command line

Comment: Then use it! **gdb** is the standard suggestion for linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:  (1) in `mergeArray`, you used `n1` in place of `n2` for `temp_b`.  Change it to:

```
int temp_b[n2];
```

(2) After creating `temp_a` and `temp_b`, after the comment "now merge these two arrays", you need to set `k` to `left` rather than `0`:

```
k = left;
```

(3) In mergeSort, your expression for `middle` is incorrect, you need to add rather than subtract:

```
int middle = ( right + left ) / 2 ;
```

It should work with these three changes.